# Why does delegate not work in "p" tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When delegate with `p` tag, it does not work http://jsfiddle.net/peswe/wbVMV/4/

HTML:

```
<p id='test'>
    <div>box 1
        <div>box in box1</div>
    </div>
</p>
```

​
JavaScript:

```
$('p#test').delegate('div','click',function(){
    alert('test');
})
```

---

Changing `p#test` to `span#test` or `body`, it works http://jsfiddle.net/peswe/wbVMV/3/

HTML:

```
<span id='test'>
    <div>box 1
        <div>box in box1</div>
    </div>
</span>
​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('span#test').delegate('div','click',function(){
    alert('test');
})
```

Please tell me something about it.Thank you very much!

Comment: It's really not usual (read: INCORRECT) to have a `div` inside a Paragraph. :) While the `<span>` elements accepts lots of standard HTML tags. `div` is a block level element. so it cannot fit inside a inline `p`

Comment: Nesting divs inside paragraphs is invalid HTML.

Comment: Please include all relevant parts of you question **in** the question as well.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Making `div` a child of `span` would not be valid either, although the other way around is fine (`span` as a child of `div`).

Comment: May be,there is something wrong with "p";wrap "p" in "div",it works;but click 'box in box1',it only alert once: http://jsfiddle.net/peswe/wbVMV/11/; but in http://jsfiddle.net/peswe/wbVMV/3/ it alert twice;

Comment: @psjscs I'm not sure why your example doesn't work, but bear in mind that as of jQuery 1.7 .delegate() has been deprecated in favour of .on(). See http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: @Olly: `.delegate()` is not *deprecated*. `.live()` is...

Comment: @FelixKling From that page: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method." Perhaps deprecated was the wrong word? :)

Comment: @OllyHodgson Even change to 'on',the result not change.

Comment: @Olly: Yeah, superseded is not deprecated... ok, I'm picky ;) I agree that using `.on()` makes more sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how browser (HTML parser) works, since `<div>` is a [Flow element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow) and `<p>` is a [Phrasing element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing), in most case an phrasing element cannot contain any flow element, this is called **misnested tags**, HTML parser would fix these issues magically with some certain steps:

1. When reading `<p>`, it generates a `<p>` element
2. When reading `<div>`, since `<div>` cannot reside in a `<p>` element, HTML parser closes the last `<p>` element, then open an `<div>` element
3. When reading `</div>`, closes the `<div>` element
4. When reading `</p>`, since previous `<p>` element is closed, parser recogonizes it as a **`<p>` element missing a start tag**, so parser automatically inserts an `<p>` start tag here to create a complete `<p>` element

Thus, the final DOM construct is:

```
<p id="test"></p> <!-- auto closed -->
<div>
  box1
  <div>
    box in box1
  </div>
</div>
<p></p> <!-- auto generated -->
```

It's obvious that the `<div>` and `<p>` is at the same level, not forming a containing relation, so delegate fails here.

Answer (score 2):

The browser is correcting your invalid HTML and moving the `div` outside of the `p`. They become siblings, hence event delegation does not work. Just inspect the elements and see for yourself:

First case:

```
<body>
  <p id="test"></p>
    <div>box 1
        <div>box in box1</div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
</body>
```

Second case:

```
<body>
  <span id="test">
    <div>box 1
        <div>box in box1</div>
    </div>
  </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `p` tag can only contain `inline elements`,
While the `<span>` tag (as being one that handles pretty well the crossbrowser identity of an inline-block element) accepts pretty well (visually cause in the code it get messed) the `div` tag, although either incorrect.

It won't validate either in strict 4.01 doctype nor in HTML5.

The appropriate way would be to wrap it in a block-level element : a `div`.